# error: Unexpected server response: 502 on trying to connect to a lambda function through Amazon API gateway Websocket API

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple Node.js 10.x **Lambda function** that works fine when tested on the [Lambda function console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda):

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var msg = 'connected';
    return { 
        statusCode: 200, 
        body: { msg: msg}
    };
};
```

I created a **WebSocket API** through their [API Gateway console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway), that integrates to it through a `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration:

[image: Websocket API on Amazon API Gateway web console]

When I try to connect to it using [wscat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-wscat.html), I get an error:

```sh
wscat -c "wss://awesomeid1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"
error: Unexpected server response: 502
```

How can I fix it?

*Bonus question:* how can we find the logs for the Websocket API connection errors?

---

Related links that didn't help me to fix it:

- [502 internal server error response from API gateway from lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051452/502-internal-server-error-response-from-api-gateway-from-lambda-function)
- [AWS - Using @connections websocket call back url to send response from back-end(one-way) - API Gateway websocket protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538274/aws-using-connections-websocket-call-back-url-to-send-response-from-back-end)
- [AWS API Gateway error response generates 502 "Bad Gateway"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847945/aws-api-gateway-error-response-generates-502-bad-gateway)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the root cause on [this answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246541#jive-message-897646). Basically, **when using a Lambda Proxy Integration**, **the Lambda function response `body` value needs to be a `string`**. We need to use `JSON.stringify()` or something similar:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var msg = 'connected';
    return { 
        statusCode: 200, 
        body: JSON.stringify({ msg: msg}) /*required on lambda proxy integration*/
    };
};
```

---

Digging into the docs, on the section [Output Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format):

> In Lambda proxy integration, API Gateway requires the backend Lambda function to return output according to the following JSON format
>
> ```
>     "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
>     "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
>     "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
>     "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
>     "body": "..." }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The output body is marshalled to the frontend as the method response payload [...]
>
> If the function output is of a different format, API Gateway returns a **502 Bad Gateway error response**.

---

*Answer to the bonus question:*

After adding a new [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) Role **`AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs`**, getting its ARN on its summary page, we can follow these steps:

[Set up API Logging Using the API Gateway Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html#set-up-access-logging-using-console)

And see that the log message on the server is more descriptive:

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response`

Comment: I had the same issues and found the same solutions (even the bonus question :D)
however, I can't get the $connect response client side?
How do you retrieve your msg ?

Comment: Are you using [wscat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-wscat.html) as a client tool? This link describes how to use it to connect to the WS API.

Comment: Yes I use wscat as well; Actually I have found my issue: I had IAM role missing the executeApi rights. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I got stung with this as well, as my $connect lambda returned `void` rather than `{statusCode:200}`, so my logic was running on the server side, but on the client, I would get a "cannot connect" error. Good find!

Answer (score 5):

As you said above, you have to stringfy all messages of your websocket to send back to your clients.

Besides that, on websocket connect method you must not **return**, because you need to keep the connection opened to receive messages.
You should calls the callback you received on **connect method** like this

```
callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
});
```

Comment: This is what worked for me.  As Pablo mentioned, make sure to use callback instead of return.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. In my case there was not requirement to return any messages on $connect.